# Unable to resolve "./utils/batch" from "node_modules\react-redux\lib\index.js"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

This error appears when I started using react redux, I tried every solution I found online but nothing

Changing react and react redux version I installed schedule,
react 16.5 with redux 6.0.0 = nothing
react 16.8.6 with redux 6.0.0 or 6.0.1 or 7.0.2 = nothing

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-saga": "^0.3.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FOUND SOLUTION
This is because you may of had a previous version of react-redux installed in node_modules in that folder name. instead of `expo start` or `npm start`. try `expo r -c`
This removes the cache in expo for that directory. Such a pain to find this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why and who, but I think it's something with **npm**, So I've just created a new project with the same dependencies versions, and It **worked !!** 
I moved all my file a created in last project to the new one, and it still working.
So If you tried every single solution out there just move to **yarn**, or create a new project with the same dependencies compatible versions, check **redux** documentation or use this one :

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-saga": "^0.3.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
```